# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serrver for mySQL

Tags: mysql

I follow this steps to install/config wordpress and mySQL, but when I do this steps:

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER
    -> ON wordpress.*
    -> TO wordpress@localhost
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'welcome';
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'welcome'' at line 4
```

Could you please let me know what goes wrong here?

Comment: The linked answer presumes you are using MySQL 8+ as this syntax did work in previous versions of MySQL like 5.7.

Comment: @Martin thanks for your reply, so what is the correct syntax then?

Comment: Ok, i saw the link with the solution
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';